# How do class methods affect instance variables in Python?

Tags: python, class

I've read throughly many posts here on the difference between class methods and instance methods. I understand them conceptually, but now I'm trying to figure out the more subtle nuances. In the example below, if I call `User.createUser('xyz')`, where does `userId` get stored? does it go to (*) below, i.e. on the instance? Or would it be as if I inserted `userId = None` where I have the comment `# placeholder` and the `userId` passed in from `User.createUser('xyz')` then assigns the class variable `userId` with `'xyz'`?

```
class User():

    # placeholder


    def __init__(self, userId):
        self.userId = userId # (*)

    @classmethod
    def createUser(cls, userId):
        if not isValid(userId): # isValid may or may not be part of the class
            return False
        else:
            return cls(userId)

    # ... other methods
```

Comment: `cls(userId)` instantiates your class, and `userId` gets passed to `__init__`. So for `User`, the `userId` will be stored in the new instance.

Comment: `cls(userId)` works exactly the same as if you did `User(userId)`, and where that value gets stored from there works exactly the same too…

Comment: in python 3 class is defined as such `class User:` without parenthesis unless if you want this class to inherent from another class then you use parenthesis `class User(User2):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classmethod createUser returns a new instance of the User object.  The parameter passed to it is stored as an attribute on this new User instance.

Comment: then why not return User(userId)?

Comment: In the case of your example, returning `cls(userId)` and `User(userId)` is identical.  The difference only becomes apparent in a child class of User.

Comment: and what would that difference be?

Comment: The difference is that `cls` refers to the current class, where `User` refers to the User class in particular.  If you have a child class `SpecialUser(User)`, using `cls` in the `createUser` method means `SpecialUser.createUser` will return a SpecialUser instead of a User

Answer (score 0):

The `userId` parameter is stored in the `__init__` method.

The call to `cls(userId)` is equivalent to a call to `User(userId)`

Answer (score 0):

In your case, neither. The `return cls(userId)` returns *a new* object*, and the `userId` is assigned to the `self` of *the new* object. So, it's neither a class nor an instance variable, it's an instance variable of another object.